# Restrict extensions on a type in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-extensions

I have a specific class in Swift that I would like to restrict extensions from being created. I tried adding the `final` keyword, but it does not restrict extensions:

```
final class MyTest {
    func testFunc() {}
}

extension MyTest {
    func testFunc2() {}
}

let test = MyTest()
test.testFunc2()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: yes it works without any error

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: GO to Playground and test it :). Happy coding.

Comment: I did. The above code is from the playground and the extension works. I want the extension NOT to work if `final` is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot prevent someone from adding an extension to your class. Like you cannot prevent another developer from writing a function that uses your class.

> The `final` modifier only prevents subclassing. Other developers will always be able to add extensions.

### Is it really a problem?

IMHO it is not.

Let's look at this class

```
final class Person {
    private let name: String
    func tellName() -> String { return "I am \(name)" }
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Now another developer could write (into another source file) this function

```
func presentAndTellName(person: Person) {
    print("Hello everybody! \(person.tellName())")
}
```

This is possible in several other programming languages that don't support extensions. Well it's basically how many programming languages work and it's one of the reasons why we have access control (private, public, ...).

Another developer infact cannot use `private` properties/methods of our class (unless it has access to our source file). He also cannot add properties to `Person` because it's a class marked as `final` so subclassing is offlimits. He can only write code that use it.

We all are fine with this right?

However writing a function that accepts a parameter and work only on that param sometimes is ugly. The function should be a method and the parameter value should be the instance.

So we use extensions to convert this

```
func presentAndTellName(person: Person) {
    print("Hello everybody! \(person.tellName())")
}
```

into this

```
extension Person {
    func presentAndTellName() {
        print("Hello everybody! \(self.tellName())")
    }
}
```

It's only a way of writing the **same logic** and making it available in a OOP syntax sugar.

Now instead of writing this

```
presentAndTellName(person)
```

we can write this

```
person.presentAndTellName()
```

### Make your stuff private

So how can you protect some of your class (/struct) logic and data from extensions? With the same mechanism you use to protect this stuff from functions external to your source file, just mark them `private`. This way other developers won't be able to use them into their extensions.

Let's look again at our Person class.

```
class Person {
    private let name: String
    func tellName() -> String { return "I am \(name)" }
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

The `name` property is market as private so **there is no way** and external function or an extension will be able to directly access it.

### Wait, what about protocols?

Ok, this is maybe the only thing where extensions offer something more than a better syntax.

Infact given this protocol

```
protocol Runner {
    func run()
}
```

we can conform to it a class we don't own

```
extension Person: Runner {
    func run() { print("") }
}
```

Comment: I wonder what the thinking behind that was, final mean final!

Comment: @TruMan1: Can I ask you what is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Preventing extensions has nothing to do with "final." Extensions outside the module can only make use of public properties and methods. There is no encapsulation goal that is furthered by requiring the syntax `myFunc(object)` rather than `object.myFunc`.

Comment: @RobNapier : yes, that's what I mean with my answer

Comment: Sorry; responding to TruMan1. Your answer is precisely correct. (I think you edited it to include all these points after these comments.)

Comment: @RobNapier: Yes I thought it was the right place to clarify that we have noting to fear from extensions since they don't put our private stuff at risk.